# Meteor: Save RegExp Object to Session

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, session, meteor

I'm trying to save a regular expression as RegExp Object in a Meteor Session for a MongoDB query, but after Session.get() the RegExp object is just a empty object.

**js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
          var obj = {};
          obj['regexp'] = new RegExp("test");
          console.log("setting regular expression: " + obj['regexp']);
          Session.set("test", obj);
    });

    Template.test.events({
        'click button': function () {
            var regex = Session.get("test");
            console.log("now it is: ");
            console.log(regex['regexp']);
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
}
```

**html**

```
<head>
  <title>meteor-regexp-session-test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> test}}
</body>

<template name="test">
  <button>hit the button and look at the console</button>
</template>
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session` package uses `ReactiveDict` under the hood.

`ReactiveDict` serializes value passed to `Sessions.set(key, value)`:

```
// https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js
// line 3-7:


var stringify = function (value) {
  if (value === undefined)
    return 'undefined';
  return EJSON.stringify(value);
};
```

`Session.get(key)` deserializes it with `EJSON.parse`:

```
// https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js
// line 8-12:

var parse = function (serialized) {
  if (serialized === undefined || serialized === 'undefined')
    return undefined;
  return EJSON.parse(serialized);
};
```

It means `Session` doesn't support `RegExp` out of the box.

The solution for your issue is to create *custom reactive data source*, which will work similar to `Session` but will not serialize/deserialize value object.

Take a look here:

- http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/48367809759/meteors-reactive-data-sources
- https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-build-a-reactive-data-source

Comment: Wow thanks. Didn't know Session deserializes with EJSON. Another reactive data source might be a local Collection (myQuery = new Meteor.Collection(null)). Or i could use the [$regex operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) so I could save the query as string. I liked the eventedmind-video - probably gonna solve it with that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the regex source instead:

```
var regex = new RegExp('test');
Session.set('regex', regex.source);

...

var restoredRegex = new RegExp(Session.get('regex'));
console.log(restoredRegex);
```

See: http://meteorpad.com/pad/KJHJtQPEapPhceXkx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but instead of doing that I would save the parameter 'test' to the Session and then create a new RegExp object. The thing is I'm creating a query object with possible multiple key-values (some of the values should be RegExp objects others not). Another possibility would be to save all regexp values in one session variable and all others to another...

Answer (score 2):

There's a handy way to teach EJSON how to serialize/parse Regular Expressions (RegExp) documented in this SO question:

[How to extend EJSON to serialize RegEx for Meteor Client-Server interactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549468/how-to-extend-ejson-to-serialize-regex-for-meteor-client-server-interactions)

Basically, we can extend the RegExp object class and use `EJSON.addType` to teach the serialization to both client and server. The options are enough of a critical piece of Regular Expressions that you should have the ability to store those too anywhere you want in perfectly valid JSON!

Hope this helps someone out there in the Universe. :)

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Adding custom types to EJSON is the way to go, because not only reactive datasources will support the type but can these types been sent via DDP over the wire, being stored in collections etc.