# how to send regex to server side in meteor

Tags: session, meteor, session-variables, meteorite

In my application, I'm building a query object some thing like below

```
Object {pointType: /analog/i, _id: Object}
```

I tried to store it in session variable,

```
Session.set("currentPointsQueryObject",queryObj);
```

Then on click event I'm getting this object

```
  var res= Session.get("currentPointsQueryObject");
  console.log(res);
```

but here I'm getting like below

```
Object {pointType: Object, _id: Object}
```

Meanwhile, I sent group_id to the server 
by geting it from session variable like

```
var group_id=Session.get("currentGroupId");
```

which is working fine(it is displaying id in server log)

Then, I've tried storing it in global variable, which returning as expected

like below on click event

```
Object {pointType: /analog/i, _id: Object}
```

but when I sent it to server side method (Immediate line after console.log() )

```
Meteor.call("updateGroupPoints",res,function(err,data){
        console.log("updated points");
        console.log(data);
    });
```

when I log `res` in server console, it is showing

```
{ pointType: {}, _id: { '$nin': [] } }
```

Althoug I have something in `pointType`, It is not passed to the server.

Anyone had idea, Is this the thing related storing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly serialize RegExp to EJSON, but you can:

```
var regexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
var serialized = regexp.source;
```

Send `serialized` and then deserialize:

```
new RegExp(serialized)
```

Take a look at : [Meteor: Save RegExp Object to Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544805/meteor-save-regexp-object-to-session)

Answer (score 1):

`/analog/i` is a regular expression, right? Values stored in `Session` and values sent to methods must be part of [EJSON](http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson) values. Regular expression aren't.

Comment: Yeah, right. Do you know any way to send regular expressions to the server side?

Comment: Doesnt provide an answer how to do it properly

Answer (score 0):

There's a handy way to teach EJSON how to serialize/parse Regular Expressions (RegExp) as of 2015 documented in this SO question:

[How to extend EJSON to serialize RegEx for Meteor Client-Server interactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549468/how-to-extend-ejson-to-serialize-regex-for-meteor-client-server-interactions)

Basically, we can extend the RegExp object class and use `EJSON.addType` to teach the serialization to both client and server. Hope this helps someone out there in the Universe. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply stringify your RegExp via `.toString()`, send it to the server and then parse it back to RegExp.