# How to extend EJSON to serialize RegEx for Meteor Client-Server interactions?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, meteor, coffeescript

I have an arbitrary (E)JSON that gets created and sent over the wire from client to server in my Meteor app. It uses `RegExp` objects  to zero-in on results:

```
# on the client
selector = 
  "roles.user": { "$ne": null } 
  "profile.email": /^admin@/gi
```

All is dandy fine on the client side, but if I pass this to the server via `Meteor.call` or `Meteor.subscribe`, the resulting (E)JSON takes this form:

```
# on the server
selector =
  "roles.user": { "$ne": null }
  "profile.email": {}
```

...and somewhere an engineer dies a little on the inside.

There are plenty of resources on the Web explaining why RegEx is unserializable via `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse` or the equivalent `EJSON` methods.

I'm not convinced RegEx serialization is impossible. So how can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reviewing [this HowTo](https://www.eventedmind.com/items/meteor-create-a-custom-ejson-type) and [the Meteor EJSON Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ejson), we may serialize RegEx using the `EJSON.addType` method.

**Extend RegExp** - Provide RegExp with the methods `EJSON.addType` requires for implementation.

```
RegExp::options = ->
  opts = []
  opts.push 'g' if @global
  opts.push 'i' if @ignoreCase
  opts.push 'm' if @multiline
  return opts.join('')

RegExp::clone = ->
  self = @
  return new RegExp(self.source, self.options())

RegExp::equals = (other) ->
  self = @
  if other isnt instanceOf RegExp
    return false
  return EJSON.stringify(self) is EJSON.stringify(other)

RegExp::typeName = ->
  return "RegExp"

RegExp::toJSONValue = ->
  self = @
  return {
    'regex': self.source
    'options': self.options()
  }
```

**Call EJSON.addType** - Do this anywhere. It's best to make it available to client AND server though. This is going to deserialize the object defined in `toJSONValue` above.

```
EJSON.addType "RegExp", (value) ->
  return new RegExp(value['regex'], value['options'])
```

**Test In Your Console** - Don't take my word for it. See for yourself.

```
> o = EJSON.stringify(/^Mooo/ig)
"{"$type":"RegExp","$value":{"regex":"^Mooo","options":"ig"}}"
> EJSON.parse(o)
/^Mooo/gi
```

And there you have a RegExp being serialized and parsed on client and server, able to be passed in over the wire, saved in a Session, and even possibly stored in a Collection of queries!

**EDIT to addess IE10+ Error: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode** Courtesy of @Tim Fletcher in the comments

```
import { EJSON } from 'meteor/ejson';

function getOptions(self) {
  const opts = [];
  if (self.global) opts.push('g');
  if (self.ignoreCase) opts.push('i');
  if (self.multiline) opts.push('m');
  return opts.join('');
}

RegExp.prototype.clone = function clone() {
  return new RegExp(this.source, getOptions(this));
};

RegExp.prototype.equals = function equals(other) {
  if (!(other instanceof RegExp)) return false;
  return EJSON.stringify(this) === EJSON.stringify(other);
};

RegExp.prototype.typeName = function typeName() {
  return 'RegExp';
};

RegExp.prototype.toJSONValue = function toJSONValue() {
  return { regex: this.source, options: getOptions(this) };
};

EJSON.addType('RegExp', value => new RegExp(value.regex, value.options));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does work great in Chrome but kills Meteor in IE 10+ with `Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode`. I fixed it with this version (ES6) https://gist.github.com/TimFletcher/1fc43b36a2710f09895613ecdd7c39a7

Answer (score 0):

There is a far simpler solution:
stringify your RegExp via `.toString()`, send it to the server and then parse it back to RegExp.