# Why does a $elemMatch MongoDB query behave differently on client and server with an extended RexExp EJSON type?

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

This is a very specialized case, but quite relevant to anyone wanting to leverage MongoDB's `RegExp` powered lookups from client (Mini-Mongo) to server (MongoDB) using publications and subscriptions *in Meteor*. **I would like to understand why the disparity between server and client MongoDB query functionality, and develop a pull-request to Meteor if it is A) needed and B) beneficial to other developers.**

**I. General Case:**

1. Run a Meteor installation with `aldeed:meteor-simple-schema`, `aldeed:collection2`, `accounts-password`, and `ejson` at a minimum.
2. **Extend** `EJSON` by adding the `RegExp` type using `EJSON.addType` with these instructions: [How to extend EJSON to serialize RegEx for Meteor Client-Server interactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549468/how-to-extend-ejson-to-serialize-regex-for-meteor-client-server-interactions)
3. Add a Meteor.user with the email address `"admin@foo.com"`
4. Run this on the Meteor server code **(UNEXPECTED RESULT)**:

   ```
   # anywhere on the server
   if Meteor.isServer
     user_selector = { 'emails': { '$elemMatch': { 'address': /^adm/ } } }
     user_count = Meteor.users.find(user_selector).count()
     console.log user_count 
     # prints 0 WHY!?
   ```
5. Run this on the MongoDB shell (bypassing Meteor.users):

   ```
   # mongo shell
   > db.users.find({ 'emails': { '$elemMatch': { 'address': /^adm/ } } }).count()
   # prints 1
   ```
6. Attempt an independent Mongo.Collection lookup with identical data.

   ```
   # server
   MyUsers = new Mongo.Collection 'myusers'
   ```
7. Copy the user document from Meteor.users() into the MyUsers collection.
8. Run this on the Meteor server **(ALSO UNEXPECTED)**:

   ```
   # anywhere on the server
   if Meteor.isServer
     user_selector = { 'emails': { '$elemMatch': { 'address': /^adm/ } } }
     user_count = MyUsers.find(user_selector).count()
     console.log user_count 
     # prints 0 WHY!?
   ```

Furthermore, if I publish ALL the users, but run the *exact* same query against the client side code (e.g. within a template helper param), the query returns the expected count.

**II. Pub/Sub Template Helper Case:**

- Publish and subscribe to users.

  ```
  # Server
  Meteor.publish 'all_users', ->
    return Meteor.users.find({})

  # Client
  Template.people.onCreated ->
    self = @
    self.peopleReady = new ReactiveVar()
    self.autorun ->
      users = Meteor.subscribe 'all_users'
      self.peopleReady.set users.ready()

  Template.people.helpers
    user_count: ->
      user_selector = { 'emails': { '$elemMatch': { 'address': /^adm/ } } }
      user_count = Meteor.users.find(user_selector).count()
      console.log user_count 
      # prints 1
      return user_count
  ```

Why the difference in the server code **demonstrated in I.4 above**? I wonder because...

- EJSON is properly extended.
- MiniMongo properly selects and counts records on the client.
- Using a MyUser Collection (instantiated with Mongo.Collection) also fails to report the correct count *on the server* but runs successfully on the client using the extended RegExp EJSON type in this query selector `{ 'emails': { '$elemMatch': { 'address': /^adm/ } } }` with identical documents outside the scope of `Meteor.user`

Where can I see (and experiment with) the server side definition of Collection.find() inside the Meteor source code?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on the server using a `meteor shell` session.

Comment: Can you try using `$regex` operator instead of the java script expression. It may be a bug that is documented somewhere.

Comment: @BatScream - No, the $regex operator does not work inside an array lookup (e.g. `'$in': [/foo/gi, /bar/gi, 'baz']`) so that's not an option. Also note that the EJSON types are properly extended and work well on the client side.  I'd like to fix the bug in any case.

Comment: Did you try with $elemMatch? Not with $in.

Comment: @BatScream - Yes, that's the example in the OP. RegExp needs to work for both.

Answer (score 0):

This does look like a bug. Please file an issue at http://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues . Be sure to follow our reproduction guidelines.

Comment: I'm digging deeper into this issue and operating on a workaround for our business case before I tackle any bug reporting. Thanks for taking the time to read through and making your recommendation!

Comment: I've started the process of formally logging the issue. I'll aim to solve it too, but I have limited bandwidth. For now, I've monkeypatched our Meteor code  to bypass the issue and deploy to Galaxy.